# How to filter collection by date range on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, collection, filter, datetime

I want to filter collection according :

- start date < today
- end date > today

I try this but my `getSlides()` function return empty results

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Vendor\Module\Api\Data\SlideInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Slide\CollectionFactory as SlideCollectionFactory;

class Carrousel extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /** @var \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Slide\CollectionFactory */
    protected $slideCollection;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Slide\CollectionFactory $slideCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        SlideCollectionFactory $slideCollection,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->slideCollection = $slideCollection;
    }

    public function getSlides()
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();

        $slides = $this->slideCollection->create()
        ->addFilter('startDate', ['lteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
        ->addFilter('endDate', ['gteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);

        return (count($slides) > 0) ? $slides : false;
    }
}
```

Please help me...

Comment: Can you provide more information on the collection you are filtering? Is this a 3rd party module or custom? It's common practice in m1/m2 for database columns to be named using underscores i.e. `start_date`

Comment: I've edit my answer

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Has force to seek and test several solutions I finally found !

Like I use `CollectionFactory` object I have to use `addFieldToFilter()` and not `addFilter()`.

```
$slides = $this->slideCollection->create()
        ->addFieldToFilter('startDate', ['lteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
        ->addFieldToFilter('endDate', ['gteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

It works perfectly!

Comment: This is super awesome, thankyou!

Comment: It might be helpful to also add an OR null condtion to also fetch those records which do not have explicitly set a from or or date. `->addFieldToFilter('from_date', [['lteq' => $today], ['null' => true]])` the same goes for 'to_date'