# Magento2.3: How to collect the data by time?

Tags: magento2.3, collection, model, resource-model

I want to collect the records from 10PM to 5AM of wishlist data. I have already created a module and not sure how to filter the records by this timeframe.

The wishlist table contains a field called Updated at. Now how can I use this field to filter the records?

Can anyone please guide me on that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function thimma\mymodule\Model\now() in /var/www/html/thimmajan3/thimma/app/code/thimma/mymodule/Model/Salesorder.php:28 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/thimmajan3/thimma/app/code/thimma/mymodule/Controller/Salesorder/Export.php(78): thimma\mymodule\Model\Salesorder->getAllTransactionaldata() #1 /var/www/html/thimmajan3/thimma/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): thimma\mymodule\Controller\Salesorder\Export->execute() #2 /var/www/html/thimmajan3/thimma/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) #3 /var/www/html/thimmajan3/thimma/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): thimma\mymodule\Controller\Salesorder\Export\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array) #4 /var/www/html/thimmajan3/thimma/vendor/magento/module-customer-segment/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(81): Butt in /var/www/html/thimmajan3/thimma/app/code/thimma/mymodule/Model/Salesorder.php on line 28
```

Comment: Can you check two links :- 1> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160230/how-to-filter-collection-by-date-range-on-magento-2  2> https://www.magemonkeys.com/magento-2-get-orders-between-a-specific-date-range/

second link use get wishlist data and add filter time . any query let me know

Answer (score 1):

Try this one "addFieldtofilter"
Change date and column as per requirement

add this code also

```
protected $date;
public function __construct(
   ....
   \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
   ....
) {
   ....
   $this->date = $date;
   ....
}
Then get value here of the undefined variable
$now = $this->date->gmtDate()->format('Y-m-d');
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($now));
$things->addFieldToFilter('created_time', array(
   'from' => $fromDate,
   'to' => $toDate,
   'date' => true,
));
```

Comment: I'm getting error for this line, $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(now()));

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Comment: Please post whole error msg , it'll be helpful to solve error.

Comment: Please check the error, I have posted it on question section

Comment: Answer updated check

Answer (score 0):

now() is a mysql function not php you can use it in sql query like this  `select now();`.

Instead you can use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` with php to retrieve current date